# LoadLibrary возвращает нули

Tags: c++, winapi, dll

Пытаюсь явно подключить dll библиотеки в свой c++ проект, вычитал, что делается это по такому принципу:

```
int main()
{
    HMODULE hLibB;

    char b[40] = "spdapi.dll";

    hLibB = LoadLibrary(LPCWSTR(b));

    cout << hLibB << endl;

}
```

После всего этого на экране появляется "00000000". Кидал dll-ку в папку проекта, указывал абсолютный путь, даже неправильный путь, все равно нули появляются. Читал на форумах, что если неправильно что-то, то должна ошибка выбиваться, а у меня нули. Подскажите пожалуйста, что я сделал не так ?

Comment: Так возврат нуля это и есть ошибка [`LoadLibrary`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/ms684175(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: А вы точно работаете с широкими строками, раз используете `LPCWSTR`? Потому что либо широкие строки, `LPCWSTR` и тогда и строка должна быть широкой, или если работа с ASCII - то использовать `LPCWSTR` - ошибка.

Comment: @Harry простите, но я честно не знаю что это такое :/ Я пытался идти как по примеру на различных сайтах и добавлять в LoadLibrary параметр string, или массив char, но компилятор ругался, говорил, что не может привести тип CHAR к LPCWSTR и тогда я решил уже так использовать. Но проблема решилась, когда я начал использовать вот такую конструкцию LoadLibrary(L"ntdll.dll").

Comment: Значит, вы работаете с широкими строками и настройки проекта соответствующие.

Answer (score 1):

Порылся немного на английской версии stackoverflow и нашел вопрос с такой же [проблемой](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8600559/loadlibrary-returning-null). Пользователь под ником Rob Kennedy так решает эту проблему:

```
LoadLibrary(L"ntdll.dll")
```

Comment: Вообще-то **решать проблему надо так: `LoadLibrary(TEXT("ntdll.dll"))`**. Это нужно для того, чтобы WinAPI-функциям строки всегда подавались в ожидаемом формате. Ведь `LoadLibrary` раскрывается либо в юникодный `LoadLibraryW()`, либо в ASCII `LoadLibraryA()` в зависимости от настроек компиляции (а именно наличия флага `-DUNICODE`).